# ¿Cómo llamar a una acción functions.php con un clic con jquery (wordpress)?

Tags: php, jquery

Quiero llamar una función específica cuando haga clic en un botón con jquery, para ejecutar la función que toma una captura de pantalla y guardarla en una carpeta, pero no quiero que me devuelvan un valor, solo quiero que ejecute esa función para tomar una captura de pantalla, recortarla, convertirla en png y guárdelo en un directorio de la imagen. Este es mi código:

```
functions.php 

    add_action("call_function","use_funtions");

function use_funtions()
{
//toma el screenshot

        $img = imagegrabscreen();

        //lo convierte en png con nombre y la redirecciona a la carpeta "img"

        imagepng($img, "imgscreen/screenshot.png");
        //obtener la url junto con el archivo png
        $imgscreen = "imgscreen/screenshot.png";

      $im = imagecreatefrompng($imgscreen);
      $size = min(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));

      //tamaño y cordenadas de la imagen

      $im2 = imagecrop($im , ['x' => 380, 'y' => 590, 'width' =>1150, 'height' => 290]);
      if ($im2 !== FALSE) {
        imagepng($im2, "imgscreen/guantes.png");
        imagedestroy($im2);
      }
      imagedestroy($im);

}

action.js

// AQUÍ INTENTO LLAMAR A LA FUNCIÓN QUE ESTÁ EN FUNCIONES.PHP

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".imprimir").on('click',function(){
        var str = "<? php use_funtions()?>" ; 

    });
})
```

;